# Groovy: List of Strings interpolated into a text loses apostrophes

Tags: groovy, string-interpolation

I would like to create a text in which I interpolate a list of stings ["aa","bb"].

```
def texts = ["aa" , "bb"]
def out = "my list: $texts"
println out
```

I want the output to be:

> my list: ["aa","bb"]

But the output I am getting is:

> my list: [aa, bb]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `texts.toString()` does not include the quotation marks. So you have to create that output yourself:

```
def out = "my list: ${texts.collect{'"' + it + '"'}}"
```